# Is there a way to listening on specific position "from left" in JS?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll, listener

Hi all I'm working on a slider, and I would that my slide detect when the horizontal scroll reaches for example 1000px from left, hence I could trigger some dynamic event - animation, CSS style, etc.

Some here know how to listen on a specific position from left?

I have tried the while loop but the stack had just overflowed,
so any hint would be great,
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect scroll position of the whole page, it should be sufficient to attach an event handler to `scroll` event of `window` element, and inside check for the value of `window.pageXOffset`. I have made a small demo in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YdmMrp). The html markup and css is just for example purposes (to have enoght content so that the whole page overflows in horizontal direction), so the important code is in js:

```
var scrollhandler = function(){
  if(window.pageXOffset > 1000){
    alert("over 1000");   
    window.removeEventListener("scroll",scrollhandler)
  }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollhandler);
```

Comment: your answer is purely awesome, I'm trying to  make it works on ReactJS, but neither componentDidMount nor a component function makes the job currently, I continue to seek for a way to make it works on React, since React is all javascript it should work someway

Comment: I just realize I need the same listener but for "automatic scrolling" when I click on a div of my slider, because seems scroll event isn't call when we don't use the scrollbar directly